# Azure Api Management returns detail error when backed is off include oath token

Tags: azure-api-management

I am working on API Management, the backend is ecured with oauth client credentials. If backend is off, I get the response of 200 and detail error as below.

```
{
  "error": {
    "name": "StatusCodeError",
    "statusCode": 404,
    "message": "HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.",
    "options": {
      "url": "https://...net.au/api/case/mycases/",
      "method": "GET",
      "headers": {
        "Authorization": "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhb....."
      },
      "simple": true,
      "resolveWithFullResponse": false,
      "transform2xxOnly": false
    },
    "response": {
      "statusCode": 404,
      "body": "HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.",
      "headers": {
        "content-length": "315",
        "content-type": "text/html; charset=us-ascii",
        "server": "Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0",
        "date": "Fri, 14 Jun 2019 02:12:36 GMT",
        "connection": "close"
      },
      "request": {
        "uri": {
          "protocol": "https:",
          "slashes": true,
          "auth": null,
          "host": ".....",
          "port": 443,
          "hostname": "....net.au",
          "hash": null,
          "search": null,
          "query": null,
          "pathname": "/api/case/mycases/",
          "path": "/api/case/mycases/",
          "href": "https://...."
        },
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
          "Authorization": "Bearer eyJ0eXAiO....."
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "status": 501
}
```

I only want to return the response like that when an api is called. and hide all extra details include access token.

```
{
  "error": {
    "name": "StatusCodeError",
    "statusCode": 404,
    "message": "HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.",
 }
}
```

as per the answer below, I have updated my policy, I am getting desired response when backend is offline but empty response when backend is online.

```
        <choose>
            <when condition="@{

               var token = context.Response.Body.As<JToken>();
               if (token is JObject){
                    return true;
               }

                return false;
            }">
                <return-response>
                    <set-status code="404" reason="NotFound" />
                    <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
                        <value>application/json</value>
                    </set-header>
                    <set-body>{
  "error": {
    "name": "StatusCodeError",
    "statusCode": 404,
    "message": "HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.",
 }
}</set-body>
                </return-response>
            </when>
        </choose>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two cases when you can get 404 response from APIM. One is when you try to call an API/operation that APIM does not know of, in that case APIM will generate 404 response and it will be very short, much like your second one.

The other case is when APIM identifies API/operation, makes a call to backend and backend responds with 404. In that scenario APIM does not treat this as a problem, and merely relays backend response to client. What you have in your first example looks like something backend would reply with. You can confirm that by making a call from test console in Azure portal and inspecting provided trace.

So what you want to do is to replace body of 404 response with one of your choosing, that can easily be done with policies. At any scope put in something along these lines:

```
<outbound>
    <base/>
    <choose>
        <when condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode == 404)">
            <return-response>
                <set-status code="404" reason="NotFound"/>
                <set-header name="Content-Type">
                    <value>application/json</value>
                </set-header>
                <set-body>{
  "error": {
    "name": "StatusCodeError",
    "statusCode": 404,
    "message": "HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found."
 }
}</set-body>
            </return-response>
        </when>
    </choose>
</outbound>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I had to change the policy a little bit now the issue is if the back end is off I got short error detail which is good but when the backend is online I get nothing in response.

```

Comment: The status code is always 200, even if the error appears.

Comment: Do context.Response.Body.As<JObject>(preserveContent: true). This will make APIM keep response body in memory, otherwise it's consumed while being parsed into JObject and is gone when it needs to be returned.